# How do I record multidimensional metrics in cloudwatch?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I want to be able to graph two or more metrics that come from the same event e.g. response times from an API versus the size of the response. Is there a way to group two or more metrics as being a multidimensional data point?

I don't see that multiple MetricDatum logged in one PutMetricDataRequest are grouped in any way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `MetricDatum` (`withDimensions`, `setDimensions`) functions.
See: https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javav2/example_code/cloudwatch/src/main/java/com/example/cloudwatch/PutMetricData.java#L62-L82

aws-cli example for multidimensions:

`aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --metric-name Buffers --namespace MyNameSpace --dimensions Name=InstanceId,Value=1-23456789 Name=InstanceType,Value=m1.small --start-time 2016-10-15T04:00:00Z --end-time 2016-10-19T07:00:00Z --statistics Average --period 60`

Comment: While the name "dimension" certainly suggests what you are saying, the documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch_concepts.html#Dimension seems to be clear that dimensions are discrete buckets that the scalar MetricDatum is binned in. That doesn't help me graph two continuous quantities against one another.